# jquery autocomplete: Select item in suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented the ui autocomplete widget.
In my case, I supply a fixed list of suggestions.

When I enter the field and it is filled, I would like to select the suggestion which equals the text in the input field.

Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried or a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Do you mean if they type in something that matches a selection without actually selecting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what you need you can add your own handler for open event, where you can decide which of the menu items will be activated. Here is my sample implementation:

```
$('#myinput').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        response(["bus", "car", "carpet", "donkey"]);
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var val = $('#myinput').val();
        var menu = $(this).data("autocomplete").menu;
        var item = menu.element.find('a:contains("' + val + '")').first();
        menu.activate($.Event({ type: "mouseenter" }), item.parent());
    }
});
```

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8X2n5/).

PS: You might be able to pull the menu object from `ui` parameter directly, but I don't see it documented and right now I am too lazy to investigate that further ;)

PS2: Also consider checking for null references when no matches are found which i didn't include..

Comment: As I said, I have a fixed list which is not reduced whilst typing. When typing and when enter the filled field, I want to have the selection set to the matching entry.

To be precise:
Let's say this is my list:
Aa-word
ab-word
ac_word

I start typing a - the first word gets selected, then b - the second entry gets selected and if I press TAB, it takes the 2. entry.
Then I enter the field again (with the entry "ab-word"). Then I want to have the second item in the List is highlited and taken when I leave the entry field.

Ok?

Comment: As you said where? I don't see an option in jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin how to use it without filtering the suggestions. Could you share a simple fiddle?

Comment: ...<br>
$input.autocomplete({
autoFocus: false,
minLength: 0,
source: function(request, response) {
  response(... a full array, sorted, but not reduced in size);
}
})
$input.autocomplete("search", '');
...<br>


Difficult to describe more than that. Possibly that way:
Enter the field with a string in it, pop up the suggestion list and pre-select the entry in that list that equals the string in the field.

Ok?

Comment: @user1596343 see updated answer.. my implementation selects first item **containing** input text, which i find more practical, but you can select whatever you want ;)

Comment: Looks like this has stopped working already in the latest version of JQuery UI. The 'activate' method names has changed to '_activate', but even if you fix it you still get an error message "this.active is null". If anyone can work out how to fix this issue, please let us know.

Comment: @cbp Replacing 'activate' with 'focus' worked for me.